# Choose which file to compile to get a module with Oasis

Tags: ocaml, oasis

I decided to switch my compilation environment from a Makefile and a configure file to Oasis.

In my `configure` file I had this command :

```
EXTERNALLIB=""
if test "$USEOCAMLFIND" = yes; then
  EXTERNALLIB=$(ocamlfind query -i-format External)
fi
```

and in my `Makefile` :

```
externalwrapper.ml: externalwrapper_actual.ml externalwrapper_fake.ml config.status
    @rm -f externalwrapper.ml
    @if [ -z "$(EXTERNALLIB)" ]; then \
    cat externalwrapper_fake.ml >> externalwrapper.ml;\
    else \
    cat externalwrapper_actual.ml >> externalwrapper.ml;\
    fi;\
    chmod -w externalwrapper.ml
```

which allowed me to compile an actual `Externalwrapper` module if the library existed in my computer and a fake one if it didn't.

Now, I try to do it in Oasis but I don't know if it's possible and, if yes, how should I do it ?

Comment: I think that this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796986/optional-dependencies-with-ocamlbuild/39797476#39797476

Comment: Well, according to the answers in this post, what should I do ? Use drup's solution or yours ? ;-)

Comment: he-he, it's your call :) Let me summarize your options in the answer, as I started to get of the space, when I tried to say in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of writing OASIS 0.4.8 supports neither optional nor conditional linking. Although you can build targets optionally, a recipe for the target should be static. There are rumors, that OASIS author is planning to add this feature in 0.4.9, but currently, he is blocked by [an issue](https://github.com/ocaml/ocamlbuild/issues/106) in ocamlbuild.

There are few workarounds, however.

### Preprocessing

You can just add an extra layer of indirection, and build your `_oasis` file froms some `_oasis.in` file. You can even use `autoconf` for this, e.g.,

```
AC_INIT([Name], [0.1-beta], [your@email])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([_oasis])  

EXTERNALLIB=$(ocamlfind query -i-format External)
WRAPPER_MODULE=externalwrapper_fake.ml
if test -z "$(EXTERNALLIB)"; then
    WRAPPER_MODULE=externalwrapper_actual.ml
fi

AC_OUTPUT
AC_SUBST(WRAPPER_MODULE)
```

And in the `_oasis.in` you can use `@WRAPPER_MODULE@` variable that will be actualized to `externalwrapper_actual.ml` or `externalwrapper_fake.ml`.

Instead of using autoconf substitutions you can actually build your own configure script that will construct `_oasis` file. For example, in BAP we are constructing a final `_oasis` file by gluing it from pieces in our custom [configure](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/configure) script.

### Use Object section and extend OCamlBuild

An alternative solution was proposed by Drup (see the [following PR](https://github.com/links-lang/links/pull/77/files) as an example). The idea is to describe each variant as a conditionally built object, and then extend OCamlbuild with a special build rule, that will, depending on a flag, find this object and link it directly.

Both solutions have their cons and pros, so we are all looking forward for the feature to be added into OASIS.

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow and let you know bug man, I love this kind of answers ! If I could give +10 to it I'd do it ! Thanks !

Comment: Well, I got a problem with what you wrote, I had to replace the `if` with `if test -z "$EXTERNALLIB"` because it was telling me `-z: command not found`. But it works perfectly, thanks !

Comment: yeah, forgot that brackets are interpreted by the m4 preprocessor. Will fix it.

Comment: This is completely unrelated but would you know why, when I execute `oasis setup` I have this error : `W: No replace section found in file configure` ?

Comment: Probably, this is because you enabled the DevFiles plugins, and it tries to overwrite your configure file. I would suggest to disable the plugin (you can keep the generated Makefile though, it doesn't depend on the _oasis file).

Comment: Great! That was, indeed, the problem!

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use flags with the name of your library and ask opam to enable them if the library is present ([oasis2opam](https://github.com/ocaml/oasis2opam) does that for you). See for example the definition of a [lwt](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-mindstorm/blob/master/_oasis#L22) flag and its use to [conditionally build a library](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-mindstorm/blob/master/_oasis#L68).  You can also have `setup.ml` [enable the flag if the library is present](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-mindstorm/blob/master/setup.ml#L48).  Finally, you can add [cppo rules in `myocamlbuild`](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-mindstorm/blob/master/myocamlbuild.ml#L22) to enable conditional code compilation.